# Html code does not display the image using the relative path

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

i am practicing html using my computer and i run the html file using the "Live Server" add-on in vscode. the image doesnt show up with the relative path:

```
<img 
        src="D/image.JPG"
        width="100"
        alt="Photo">
```

when i follow the link , an error is shown but i have no idea why the error is being shown

Comment: What is the error shown? Can you update with a screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to link to the image in your D drive? If so, you need to correct the path:

src="D:/image.jpg"